# Best programming language to periodically search a website, parse it and mail results?

Tags: web-applications, programming-languages

What programming language would be the best to create a program that would query a website every **x** minutes on a Windows system? Also, after getting the information, I would like to parse it and send the parsed information via email.

I had asked a similar question yesterday and it seemed like **Python** was the way to go but some also suggested `wget`.  I added from yesterday's question the requirement to email the parsed results hence the repost.

Thanks.

Comment: "Best" is not a question with a reasonable answer.  Python would be perfectly fine, but so would any number of other technologies.  A question where you have a specific set of constraints, and are comparing specific technologies against those constraints is much more likely to have a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very subjective - how are you defining "best"?  This does not seem like a particularly performance-intensive application; I would use whichever language you are most comfortable with that will do the job.  If you have more than one to pick from, pick the one that will let you complete the application the quickest.